# No idea why my Livewire function is not working?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

For some reason all of the livewire functions in my program have suddenly stopped working and I have no idea why. For example when I click the function to add friend it doesn't fire at all

This is what my app.blade.php part looks like

```
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

        <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

        <!-- Fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&display=swap">

        <!-- Styles -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
        <link href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>


@livewireStyles

                <!-- Scripts -->
    
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">--}}
            <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
            @livewireScripts
        </head>
        <body class="font-sans antialiased">
```

This is what the AddFriend component class looks like:

```
class AddFriend extends Component
{
//    public $user;

    public function render()
    {
        $users = User::where('id', '!=', Auth::user()->id)->limit(14)->latest()->get();

        $usersid=User::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->pluck('id');



        $attribute= Attribute::whereIn('user_id',$usersid)->get();
       // dd($attribute);
        return view('livewire.add-friend', compact('users'));
    }

    public function addToFriend($id)
    {
        try {
            $user = Auth::user();
            $recipient = User::find($id);
            if (!$recipient) {
                $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert', ['type' => 'error', 'message' => 'User not found!']);
            } else {
                if ($user->befriend($recipient)) {
                    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert', ['type' => 'success', 'message' => 'Request has been sent!']);

                } else {
                    $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert', ['type' => 'error', 'message' => 'Request has been failed!']);
                }
            }

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('alert', ['type' => 'error', 'message' => $e->getMessage()]);
        }
    }
```

This is what the all_users.blade.php looks like:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

@if ($message = Session::get('success'))
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        <p>{{ $message }}</p>
    </div>
@endif


<article>

<div>
        @livewire('add-friend')
</div>
```

This is the main part where the livewire function gets rendered(add-friend.blade.php):

```
<div>
@foreach ($users as $user)
<div render:poll="render">
    <h3>{{$user->name}}</h3>

@if($user->attributes!=null)
    <p>Grade is {{$user->attributes->GradeLevel}}</p>
    <p>Age is {{$user->attributes->Age}}</p>
    <p>Country is {{$user->attributes->Country}}</p>
@endif
            @if(Auth::user()->hasSentFriendRequestTo($user))
                <x-button  type="submit" class="btn btn-red">Requested</x-button>
            @elseif(Auth::user()->isFriendWith($user))
                <x-button class="btn btn-green"  type="submit" >Friends</x-button>
            @else
                <button  wire:click="addToFriend({{ $user->id }})" class="btn btn-warning" type="button" > Add Friend</button>
            @endif


    </div>
@endforeach


</div>
```

I'm not sure what the issue as I'm being told that its to do with the div functions but they work, so it could be anything really. I don't know why all of the livewire functions have all stopped working and normal functions work fine

Comment: That `href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com ...` line with the ending blade comment `--}}` doesn't look suspicious to you?

Comment: Removed it but still doesn't seem to work